# Creating new date object with format (mm/dd/yyyy) fails in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This fails in IE 11 but works fine in Chrome.
//where startDate is "10/17/2016"

```
var testDate1 = new Date(startDate);
```

This gives an invalid date in IE with the debugger, but works fine in Chrome.

According to MSDN, this should work
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Another example, just playing with the date format
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `var testDate1 = new Date(2016, 9, 17); ` for IE

Comment: **IE11** gives `[date] Mon Oct 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)[date] Mon Oct 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)` **Edge** gives `[date] Mon Oct 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)` What's wrong?

Comment: With regards to @DavidR's comment, do note that the month (correctly set to 9 in his example) is 0-11 as opposed to 1-12.  Otherwise, day and year are normal.  This is frequently a point of confusion with javascript date formatting.

Comment: If `"10/17"` gives `October 17` I can't see anything wrong... Chrome gives the same `Mon Oct 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)`

Comment: Actually I can't seem to reproduce any kind of error.  Is the issue somewhere else in your code? http://i.stack.imgur.com/HzU89.jpg https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/fcwftvv0/

Answer (score 0):

For certain result you may split datestring and use new Date function as below.
On Date constructor Months are array 0 to 11. So we have to use -1. If your datestring is not a valid date then below function returns null.

```
function MakeDate(DString) /*10/17/2016*/
{ DString=DString.split('/');
return new Date(DString[2], parseInt(DString[0])-1, DString[1]);
}
```